# Using Live Reload with Jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I'm getting started with [Jekyll static site generator](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) and I would like to use [Live Reload](http://livereload.com) with it. I know Jekyll has a generator and server commands, and Live Reload can run various compilers and custom commands. How do I configure these to work together?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As pointed out in other answers, LiveReload is built into Jekyll 3.7+.

```
jekyll serve --livereload
```

---

#### For older versions:

The simplest approach I've found that works is to use two terminal windows: One for `jekyll serve --watch` and one for `guard`.

I tried the [guard-jekyll-plus approach suggested by Nobu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22649482/198452) but I had a bunch of errors.

As [shumushin pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16597868/198452), Jekyll can handle the automatic rebuilding process, you simply launch it using `jekyll serve --watch`

Now to get LiveReload working run guard with guard-livereload in a second terminal window. This is basically the same as [Jan Segre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173204/198452), but without `guard-jekyll`.

My `Guardfile` looks like this:

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(/^_site/)
end
```

And my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jekyll'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-livereload'
```

**Note**: You still need to include the livereload script in your `index.html` page; it is the "glue" that binds `guard-livereload` and the browser together.

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Comment: Simple and works. While using with [Pow](http://pow.cx), I replaced `jekyll serve -w` with `jekyll build -w`. Though it gives a duplicate watched notice now, maybe because Pow is also watching for changes?

Comment: I'm getting a `403 Forbidden`. Any idea? Using `bundle exec guard`

Comment: The `--livereload` parameter was introduced on Jekyll 3.70. From now on you just need to type: `jekyll s -l`.

Answer (score 56):

LiveReload is built into Jekyll 3.7+.

```
jekyll serve --livereload
```

You can also set LiveReload's port, delay, and ignored files. See `jekyll help serve`.

Answer (score 23):

For jekyll 1.0+ use:

```
jekyll serve --watch
```

See [Jekyll: Basic Usage](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/usage/) for more details and options.

Comment: This question is relatively old compared to the latest improvements to Jekyll. Thanks for following up with an answer for newer versions.

Comment: This doesn't notify LiveReload though, does it?

Comment: LiveReload is not needed. Jekyll will reload the page automatically on changes to watched folders.

Comment: This is not correct. Jekyll will recompile everything, but it doesn't handle any live reloading/refreshing with the actual browser, unfortunately.

Comment: Why is this answer up-voted so much? The question was asking about LiveReload not auto-regenerating through the `--watch` flag.

Comment: I downvoted this answer; it *does not* answer the original question.

Comment: This is not the answer

Answer (score 23):

There's [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) which you can use with [guard-jekyll](https://github.com/therabidbanana/guard-jekyll) and centralize the watching process with [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), an example would be (I haven't tested it):

- Install guard-jekyll, either through gem or bundler
- Install guard-livereload, either through gem or bundler

Init guard-jekyll

```
guard init jekyll
```

Add this to your Guardfile:

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{_site/.+})
end
```

You can adapt the above to suit better your project, and
you probably already know you have to include the livereload
script on your page:

```
<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
```

Oh, and to start the whole watching mess:

```
guard
```

Comment: Cool, thanks! I tried this once before, but later realized I had another livereload server running that I didn't know about. I'll give it another try.

Comment: There's an [option](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload#options) to change the port, it can get messy sometimes always using the same port.

Comment: Hey man, there's an extra paren at `livereload watch(%r{_site/.+)})`, should be `watch(%r{_site/.+})`.

Comment: inserting the `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>` is not so good as this pieces probably don't need to be committed to git.

Comment: @zyxue that's true, though it's very reasonable to add some conditional to render it on the template, like `{{#dev}}<script ...></script>{{/dev}}`

Comment: I use  ` <!-- live reload --> {% if jekyll.environment != "production" %} <script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script> {% endif %} ` to load it condictionally.

Comment: Why is this needed: `group :development do gem 'guard-livereload', '~> 2.5', require: false end` as seen [here](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload)?

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE: this no longer works with the latest version of Jekyll

```
cd your/site/folder
jekyll --server --auto
```

Comment: cf. @shumushin's answer for recent versions of Jekyll.

Comment: Question is about LiveReload, this does not address the question.

Answer (score 13):

This post explains a cleaner way - [Setting Up LiveReload With Jekyll](http://dan.doezema.com/2014/01/setting-up-livereload-with-jekyll/)

Gemfile:

```
gem 'jekyll'
gem 'guard'
gem 'guard-jekyll-plus'
gem 'guard-livereload'
```

Guardfile:

```
guard 'jekyll-plus', :serve => true do
  watch /.*/
  ignore /^_site/
end

guard 'livereload' do
  watch /.*/
end
```

Install [any LiveReload browser extension](http://feedback.livereload.com/knowledgebase/articles/86242-how-do-i-install-and-use-the-browser-extensions-). Then run `guard`.

Comment: This worked for me. kikito's, balexand's, shumushin's answers do not cause the browser to reload, and the accepted answer did not work for me (outdated, I suspect)

Comment: I had issues with this on Windows, as it lacks fork()

Answer (score 11):

I wrote a Jekyll plugin called [Hawkins](https://github.com/awood/hawkins) that incorporates LiveReload into the Jekyll `watch` process.  It works with Jekyll 3.1 and up.

Simply add

```
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'hawkins'
end
```

to your Gemfile (and then a `bundle install`).  From there you can run `jekyll liveserve`.  Hawkins will modify the `head` sections of your pages to include the necessary components for LiveReload, and when Jekyll detects a page change, Hawkins will push a message to your browser via WebSockets.  Please note that you will need a browser that supports [WebSockets](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets).  For very fast reloads, you can use Jekyll's new `--incremental` option that will only regenerate the changed pages.

Comment: I have checked and Hawkins is only compatible with Jekyll 3.1 and up.

Comment: Fantastic, no stuff with this guard etc, indeed just works. Might want to add "bundle init" but people could just figure that out :-)

Answer (score 5):

This command will open your website in the browser and uses jekyll built-in livereload server.

`bundle exec jekyll serve -l -o`

You need a latest jekyll version.

Answer (score 4):

Start by running jekyll normally in your site folder:

```
cd your/site/folder
jekyll
```

By default Jekyll generates a folder called `_site` inside it (`your/site/folder/_site`).

Tell LiveReload to watch that `_site` folder.

Comment: will the `jekyll` command watch for file changes and regenerate them automatically?

Comment: Yes, if the "auto" variable is set to true in the config file or the command line. See it here: https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration

Comment: The purpose of LiveReload in this situation is to reload the page dynamically so you don't have to. It's still useful, you just don't happen to need half of LiveReload's features for jekyll's generators anyway.

Comment: This is the easiest way to make this happen - you don't need to mess with guard files at all

Answer (score 1):

I just started using GitHub Pages today, and wanted to be able to use live reload with Jekyll.  Got it working & written my first post on [Creating GitHub Pages with Jekyll & LiveReload](http://bit.ly/1d2iV03).

It uses Grunt with the `grunt-contrib-watch` plugin instead of Jekyll's `serve` command - works well for me. Hope it works for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just `jekyll serve -w`, an option I prefer as I am lazy.

Answer (score 0):

For Live Reload,
Remove **Jekyll Admin** from ***Gemfile*** in the root directory of your project and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running it frequently, the [Repla](https://repla.app) macOS app makes it easy to startup Jekyll so it automatically refreshes. After Repla is installed, you run it from the Jekyll blog's root directory and pass it the `jekyll serve` command. For example:

```
repla server "bundle exec jekyll serve --watch --drafts" -r "...done"
```

Repla will be configured to refresh each time `...done` is printed in the console, which Jekyll prints when it finishes compiling your site.

Repla runs the Jekyll server process in a split below a browser split showing your site:

[image: Jekyll in Repla]

After Jekyll is running in Repla, you can also save the configuration to a file with `⌘S`, shut it down by closing the window, and run it again just by double-clicking the file. In other words, you can start your Jekyll blog again next time just by opening the file, without involving the terminal at all.

Disclosure: I maintain the Repla app.