# error using jekyll with guard

Tags: bundler, jekyll, guard, livereload

I am trying to use jekyll with livereload like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19173204/2112538):

The project is using [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) with the `github-pages` gem (jekyll v.2.4), so `guard-jekyll`and `guard-livereload` are added to the Gemfile and then I make `bundle install` and `guard init`. this is throwing an error starting with:

```
ERROR - Could not load 'guard/jekyll' or find class Guard::Jekyll
```

`bundle exec guard init` is doing the same error.

**EDIT:** the problem is the same as described [here (3rd step)](http://www.jon-long.ca/jekyll/2013/12/04/getting-jekyll-to-work.html)

Comment: I assume you have done a `bundle install`

Comment: @DaniëlW.Crompton yes. I add it in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guard-jekyll` is outdated (it might be updated, but I'm not the author, so I don't have access to releasing it - though that may change).

Either way, I recommend using `guard-jekyll-plus`, since it does everything `guard-jekyll` does (which only runs the build) plus more (runs a server automatically, handles handles more file types, and copies static assets).

Although, there may be a pending update to `guard-jekyll-plus` soon. (Watch the repository for updates: https://github.com/imathis/guard-jekyll-plus).

Also, if you use the default template in any of those projects (by running `bundle exec guard init`), you may want the latest version (2.10.3) of Guard (fixes for ignore rules).

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question here: https://github.com/guard/guard/issues/689

and it's looking like a bug related to guard-jekyll…