# Jekyll autoreload browser page

Tags: jekyll, livereload, browser-sync

It's possible to have a livereload (or browsersync) like system that run with `jekyll serve` without using other tools like grunt/gulp?

What I'm expecting is to edit a css, sass, html or md file and have the browser page auto reloading.

I'm using Jekyll 2.5.x

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395526/using-live-reload-with-jekyll

Comment: doesn't @DC.Azndj not answer your question?, although 3 years later!

Answer (score 6):

As of January 2018, [Jekyll 3.7](https://jekyllrb.com/news/2018/01/02/jekyll-3-7-0-released/) now has the `--livereload` flag.

`jekyll serve` automatically rebuilds the `_site` folder whenever changes are saved.

`--livereload` refreshes the browser with those changes.

So, use `jekyll serve --livereload`.

Comment: Thank You very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Saved me a ton of time. Thank you.

Comment: No need for a VS Plugin.